# Which is correct:了 or 过 in 我去。。。他家，知道他住在哪里

Tags: grammar, word-choice

```
我去。。。他家，知道他住在哪里.
```

I do not know what to choose in this sentence: 了 or 过. In my opinion:

(1) 我去了他家，知道他住在哪里. (I had been to his house)

(2) 我去过他家，知道他住在哪里. (I had had the experience of being in his house)

Question: **Is what I think correct?** If wrong, please explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

了 indicates the verb is 'completed action'

过 indicates the verb is 'experienced action'

我去过 他家，知道他住在哪里.  (I **had gone** to his house **before**,  so I know where he lives) is the correct one

去过 = had gone before

去了 = have gone to